# Remove custom post type from the auto generated list on the edit menu page Add menu items

Tags: admin-menu

How to remove a custom post type from the default wordpress admin menu editor nav-menus.php ?
I'm sure this is already talked about but I can't find it in stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

As [documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters), when using `register_post_type()` set `show_in_nav_menus` to `false`.